# Durandal - activation invoked two times in Master Detail sample

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

In [Master Detail sample](http://durandaljs.com/pages/samples/#master-detail) on Durandal website, `project.activate` function is invoked two times each time when I change project in dropdown list.

First activation is invoked in `write` method of `Activator`. Second activation is invoked in `composition.bindAndShow`.

If I'm right, an obvious fix would be replacing (in `index.html`) this

```
<!--ko compose: activeProject--><!--/ko-->
```

with this

```
<!--ko compose: { model: activeProject, activate: false }--><!--/ko-->
```

but Durandal [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/) says in Using Composition > Additional Settings > Activate:

> Note: If you are using an activator, it will control the activation call and you should not attempt to manipulate it via the compose binding.

So I shouldn't do that. What is a proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround what about setting a `runInit` flag in the ctor, which gets set to false during activate?

```
var ctor = function(name, description) {
    this.runInit = true;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
};


ctor.prototype.activate = function() {
    if (this.runInit){
        this.runInit = false;
        system.log('Model Activating', this);
    }
};
```

Live version available at http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#master-detail/so19719038

In addition I'd raise that as an issue https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues?state=open to check if the double activation is expected or not.

Comment: I'm doing something simillar at the moment but I'm blocking first activation and allowing second activation (from composition) as it works better with Knockout. The downside is that I've to do that in every viewmodel affected. A plugin solution would be better... If you know how to do that (block activation from Activator) in plugin I would love to hear!

Comment: Having said that I still need Activator for deactivation now and maybe for more in future. Just don't need it's activate invoke :)

Comment: As said above I'm not sure if the behavior you're seeing is by design.  It would be best to raise it as an issue.